# pigpio I2C reply value

Tags: raspbian, i2c, pigpio

I'm sending a command e.g. "wifion" with I2C arduino(master) to RPI(slave)
That works perfect but I need to return a confirmation value.

How can I send back/reply from the RPI to the Ardunio a value?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# bsc_arduino.py
# 2016-10-31
# Public Domain

import time
import pigpio
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import subprocess
import os

SDA=18
SCL=19

I2C_ADDR=28

print "Start"
def i2c(id, tick):
   global pi
   s, b, d = pi.bsc_i2c(I2C_ADDR)
   #GPIO.output(17, GPIO.HIGH)
   if b:
      #print(d[:-1])
      if d=="wifion":
        print "An"
        os.system ('rfkill unblock wifi')

      if d=="wifioff":
        print "Aus"
        os.system ('rfkill block wifi')

      print d

pi = pigpio.pi()
if not pi.connected:
    exit()
# Add pull-ups in case external pull-ups haven't been added
pi.set_pull_up_down(SDA, pigpio.PUD_UP)
pi.set_pull_up_down(SCL, pigpio.PUD_UP)
# Respond to BSC slave activity
e = pi.event_callback(pigpio.EVENT_BSC, i2c)
pi.bsc_i2c(I2C_ADDR) # Configure BSC as I2C slave
time.sleep(600)
e.cancel()
pi.bsc_i2c(0) # Disable BSC peripheral
pi.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `i2c` function add the data that you want to transmit as a reply:

```
pi.bsc_i2c(I2C_ADDR, data=["your data here"])
```

Comment: Tried it but get this error :  ValueError: string must be of size 1

Comment: @user3435167, what exactly did you try to pass as `data`?

Comment: I added ', data=["your data here"]' as you suggested to my code to see if it replys with a word/number

Comment: @user3435167, try just sending a character `data="A"`

Comment: There is also no reaction. i guess there's a problem with my master's code then..

Comment: Do you get any error message? Or is it just not reacting?

Answer (score 0):

With the I²C bus, each module can become master or slave at any moment. 
Check the smbus library in python, it's by default on the Raspberry.

In the python shell: `help(smbus.SMBus)`

You have functions to read and write data with I²C bus, juste give him the address of the device you want to communicate with (your Arduino).

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not using the regular I2C pins but SDA=18
SCL=19 instead.